# Trouble rearranging my y axis variables using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a graph that needs to be sorted by frequency. I have figured out how to move the variables on the y axis into a decreasing order but it is sorted by the x variable values rather than the number of times the x variable comes up.

I have tried using this bit of code

```
p<- ggplot(a, aes(x=reorder(Analyte,a$Concentration),y=a$Concentration), na.rm=TRUE)
```

but it is not ordering in the way I would like.

```
a<-Analyte_Concentrations

p<- ggplot(a, aes(x=reorder(Analyte,a$Concentration),y=a$Concentration), na.rm=TRUE)

p  +  geom_boxplot(fill= "white", na.rm=TRUE)  + coord_flip() +
  geom_point(aes(color = Analyte)) + ggtitle("  Analyte Detection Concentrations  ") + 
  xlab("Analytes (decreasing concentration)") + ylab("Concentration")
```

Example of Data:

```
52  Nicotine    -2.3010300
53  Nicotine    -2.1549020
54  Nicotine    -2.2218487
55  Nicotine    -2.3010300
56  Nicotine    -2.0000000
57  Nicotine    -2.2218487
58  Nicotine    -2.0457575
59  Nicotine    -2.0969100
60  Nicotine    -2.1549020
61  Tris(chloropropyl) phosphate    -1.6989700
62  Tris(chloropropyl) phosphate    -2.0000000
63  Tris(chloropropyl) phosphate    -2.0000000
64  Tris(chloropropyl) phosphate    -2.0000000
65  Tris(chloropropyl) phosphate    -1.6989700
66  Tris(chloropropyl) phosphate    -1.6989700
67  Tris(chloropropyl) phosphate    -1.6989700
68  Tris(chloropropyl) phosphate    -1.6989700
69  Tris(chloropropyl) phosphate    -2.0000000
70  Tris(chloropropyl) phosphate    -1.1549020
71  cis-Testosterone    -2.1249387
72  cis-Testosterone    -2.2596373
73  Acesulfame-K    -0.9208188
74  Acesulfame-K    -1.0969100
75  Acesulfame-K    -1.1549020
76  Acesulfame-K    -0.9208188
77  Acesulfame-K    -0.9208188
78  Acesulfame-K    -1.2218487
79  Acesulfame-K    -1.2218487
80  Acesulfame-K    -1.2218487
81  Acesulfame-K    -0.7958800
82  Acesulfame-K    -1.2218487
83  Acesulfame-K    -1.2218487
84  Acesulfame-K    -1.6989700
85  Acesulfame-K    -0.9208188
86  Acesulfame-K    -0.9586073
87  Acesulfame-K    -0.8239087
88  Acesulfame-K    -0.7695511
89  Acesulfame-K    -0.1611509
90  Acesulfame-K    -0.9586073
91  Acesulfame-K    -0.9586073
92  Acesulfame-K    -1.3979400
93  Acesulfame-K    -0.9208188
94  Acesulfame-K    -1.0000000
95  Acesulfame-K    -1.6989700
96  Acesulfame-K    -0.8860566
97  Acesulfame-K    -1.0457575
98  Acesulfame-K    -0.8860566
99  Acesulfame-K    -1.0000000
100 Acesulfame-K    -0.3872161
101 Cotinine    -3.0000000
102 Cotinine    -3.0000000
103 Cotinine    -3.0000000
104 Cotinine    -3.0000000
105 Cotinine    -3.0000000
106 Cotinine    -3.0000000
107 Cotinine    -3.0000000
108 Cotinine    -3.0000000
109 Cotinine    -2.6989700
110 Cotinine    -3.0000000
111 Cotinine    -3.0000000
112 Cotinine    -3.0000000
113 Cotinine    -3.0000000
114 Cotinine    -2.6989700
115 Cotinine    -3.0000000
116 Cotinine    -3.0000000
117 Cotinine    -2.6989700
118 Cotinine    -3.0000000
119 Cotinine    -3.0000000
120 Cotinine    -2.6989700
121 Cotinine    -2.6989700
122 Cotinine    -2.5228787
123 Cotinine    -3.0000000
124 Cotinine    -3.0000000
125 Cotinine    -3.0000000
126 Cotinine    -3.0000000
127 Cotinine    -3.0000000
128 Sulfamethoxazole    -3.0000000
129 Sulfamethoxazole    -3.0000000
130 Sulfamethoxazole    -3.0000000
131 Sulfamethoxazole    -3.0000000
132 Sulfamethoxazole    -3.0000000
133 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
134 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
135 Sulfamethoxazole    -3.0000000
136 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
137 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
138 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
139 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
140 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
141 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
142 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
143 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.5228787
144 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
145 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
146 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
147 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
148 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
149 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
150 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
151 Sulfamethoxazole    -3.0000000
152 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
153 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
154 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
155 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
156 Sulfamethoxazole    -3.0000000
157 Sulfamethoxazole    -3.0000000
158 Sulfamethoxazole    -3.0000000
159 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
160 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
161 Sulfamethoxazole    -2.6989700
162 Sulfamethoxazole    -3.0000000
163 DEET    -2.0969100
164 DEET    -2.1549020
165 DEET    -1.9208188
166 DEET    -2.3010300
167 DEET    -2.0969100
168 DEET    -2.2218487
169 DEET    -1.8239087
170 DEET    -2.2218487
171 DEET    -2.1549020
172 DEET    -2.0969100
173 DEET    -2.1549020
174 DEET    -2.2218487
175 DEET    -2.3010300
176 DEET    -2.1549020
177 DEET    -2.0969100
178 DEET    -2.0969100
179 DEET    -2.2218487
180 DEET    -2.1549020
181 DEET    -2.2218487
182 DEET    -2.2218487
183 DEET    -2.2218487
184 DEET    -2.1549020
185 DEET    -1.9586073
186 DEET    -2.0000000
187 DEET    -2.0969100
188 DEET    -2.0969100
189 DEET    -2.0969100
190 DEET    -2.2218487
191 DEET    -2.3010300
192 DEET    -2.1549020
193 DEET    -2.1549020
194 DEET    -2.2218487
195 DEET    -2.2218487
196 DEET    -2.0969100
197 DEET    -2.2218487
198 DEET    -1.8239087
199 DEET    -1.6382722
200 DEET    -1.8860566
201 DEET    -2.2218487
202 DEET    -1.8538720
203 DEET    -1.9208188
204 DEET    -1.8538720
205 DEET    -2.0457575
206 DEET    -2.1549020
207 DEET    -2.0000000
208 DEET    -2.1549020
209 DEET    -2.3010300
210 DEET    -2.2218487
211 DEET    -2.2218487
212 DEET    -2.2218487
213 DEET    -1.8239087
214 DEET    -2.2218487
215 DEET    -2.0457575
216 DEET    -2.0969100
217 DEET    -2.0000000
218 DEET    -2.1549020
219 DEET    -2.2218487
220 DEET    -2.2218487
221 DEET    -2.2218487
222 DEET    -1.8239087
223 DEET    -2.2218487
224 DEET    -2.0969100
225 DEET    -2.3010300
226 DEET    -2.1549020
227 DEET    -1.8538720
228 DEET    -1.8538720
229 DEET    -2.2218487
230 DEET    -2.0457575
231 DEET    -2.3010300
```

I would like the graph to be ordered in decreasing occurence levels. So Deet on the top and nicotine on the bottom in the data excerpt above.

Comment: Perhaps try `aes(x = forcats::fct_infreq(Analyte)...`

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly.